# What exactly is Response Time metric from App Service

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, metrics

Is it the same as "Time Taken (time-taken)" from IIS Logs as described [here](https://forums.iis.net/post/1969130.aspx)?

> Time-taken is the time it takes from when IIS receives the first byte in the request until it sends out the last byte in that request. This includes network time getting to the client (for nearly all cases if you have a page that is less than 2KB, I think, that is cached) so a slow network connection will have a longer network time and thus time taken.
>   The start time of when the first byte is received by IIS is the "time" field and the finish time when IIS sends out that the last byte is the "time" field + the "time-taken" field

Comment: Did you mean Average Response Time metrics ?

Comment: yes, Average Response Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Average response times** is a composite metric composed of 2 metrics.

**1) #of Requests**

**2) Sum of response times for a sample.**

We **publish metrics every 10s, so 6 samples in a minute.** This means every 10 s we publish number of requests in that 10s and the Sum of response times in that 10s.

It does not have **information about response time for each request**. The smallest granularity is 1 minute so aggregates the 6 samples calculate computed sampling types (Average, Sum, Max, Min) .

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it adds more clarity in the way it is calculated. However I am more interested in what "response time" represents (the one which you mention is summarized every 10 seconds).

Comment: Response Time -- "Measures the time between a web request entering your application and the response being returned"

Comment: From the definition I understand that the time for reaching the client is not included. Meaning that in case the client has a poorer internet connection this metric will not be affected, is that correct?

Comment: How does "Average Response Time (Deprecated)" compare to "Response Time" (with either the Avg or Sum aggregation)? And why do I get very different results for each metric?